# Multiple if statements in a row do not work?

Tags: php, if-statement, drupal

So I put this into my script

```
if (!isset($params['q']) || !$params['q']) {
    $params['q'] = 'trending';
}


if (!isset($params['meal']) || !$params['meal']) {
    $params['meal'] = 0;
}

if (!isset($params['sort']) || !$params['sort']) {
    $params['sort'] = 0;
}

    $params = array_unique($params);
```

Now the weird thing that happens is `$params['q'] = 'trending'` and `$params['meal'] = 0`
but suspiciously the `sort` will be dropped out altogether.  If I put `sort` ahead of `meal`, instead of `meal` showing up `sort` will show up.  If I put `sort` after another command then all three will list.  Is there something I am missing here?  It seems as if, in php, I cannot do more than two if statements in a row?

```
    array (size=2)
    'q' => string 'trending' (length=8)
    'meal' => int 0
```

This is with out changing order, now if I were to put a command between if statement 2 and 3 I get

```
    array (size=3)
    'q' => string 'trending' (length=8)
    'meal' => int 0
    'sort' => int 0
```

Which is what I want

Comment: Could you post the output of a `var_dump($params);` right after this piece of code?

Comment: Works fine for me - I got { ["q"]=> string(8) "trending" ["meal"]=> int(0) ["sort"]=> int(0) } from the var_dump.

Comment: There must be something else interfering. Could you add some more of your original code before and after the snippet? (is this a direct cut&paste or could it be that the braces are a little different in your code?)

Comment: Something tells me this isn't the entire code...

Comment: Yeah you are right...  The issue seems to be with array_unique() ...  Hmmmmmm  I will upload the rest.  I don't know why it is getting rid of one of them, they are not the same, their keys are completely different ...  Wait maybe it doesn't like that it is not string data passed in.  Hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to see if the key exists at all? If so, you may want to use `array_key_exists`, like this:

```
if (!array_key_exists('q', $params)) {
    $params['q'] = 'trending';
}

if (!array_key_exists('meal', $params) {
    $params['meal'] = 0;
}

if (!array_key_exists('sort', $params) {
    $params['sort'] = 0;
}

$params = array_unique($params);
```

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks! :D  But it seems my problem is now with array_unique.  I guess I am going to have to make my own function in order to make sure there are no repeats.